# What is the solution to the family puzzle?

Tags: remember-me

I've arrived at three pillars, each with a hologram presumably representing my father, mother, and I, as a child.

[image]

Each pillar has a variety of words above it; the father has the words 'Admire', 'Protect' and 'Listen', the mother has the words 'Console', 'Abandon' and 'Listen' and the child representing Nilin has the words 'Listen', 'Fear' and 'Love'.

[image]

I appear to be able to rotate the words around each column from the floor above, so I am assuming this is a word matching puzzle of some kind.

What combinations of words do I need to select to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make the Mom turn so Listen is facing the Father and Abandon is facing
> the child
>
> Make the Father turn so Admire is facing the Mother, Protect
> is facing the Child
>
> Make the Child turn so Love is facing the Mother
> and Father.

Source [is IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/remember-me/Episode_7_-_Paradise_Lost)